# C warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, strtol

EXPLANATION:

simply trying to convert a a char to hexadecimal but i keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to get around this

PROBLEM:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strtol’ makes pointer from integer without a cast[cs214111@cs lab3]$ vi lab3.c
```

CODE:

```
void print_group(char array[])
{
    int num,a;
    char ch[10];

    printf("here ");    
    for (a = 0 ; a < 8 ; a++)
    {
        strcpy(ch,array[3]);  
        num = strtol(ch,0,16);//------------------THIS IS IT//
        printf("%i",num);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `array[3]` is not an address.

Comment: What is it about the error that you find ambiguous?  You are passing an integer (a char is a type of integer) as the first argument to strtol instead of a pointer.  Don't do that.

Comment: use either `array + 3` or use `&array[3]` for the second argument.  The second argument needs to be a `char *` or char pointer and you are passing a `char` instead. And this `char` in turn is being promoted to an integer. Do you have an `#include <string.h>` in your file in order to declare a prototype for the `strcpy()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `char` where `char *` is expected, maybe

```
strcpy(ch, &array[3]);
```

But from your code it would seem like this, is what you actually need

```
num = strtol(&array[3], 0, 16);
```

if `strcpy()` works in this case, then this will work.